# Applying a layout from a second slide master in Powerpoint using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, layout, powerpoint

I am creating slides and inserting a large (several MB sized) image onto each one into an existing `pptx`. I want to use a layout from another presentation though. I can get the master to import from the template but when I use `.ApplyTemplate("desiredTemplate")`.  But how do I get the new slide to have the imported `.ppLayoutTitleOnly` layout as opposed to powerpoint's original `TitleOnly` layout?

```
 Private Sub PPTGeneratorAL(ByVal imageArr As List(Of String), ByVal alReportName As String)

        Const sTemplate = "C:\temp\script\testtemplate2.potx"

        Dim oApp As PowerPoint.Application
        Dim oPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
        Dim oSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
        Dim scaleFactor As Decimal

        oApp = New PowerPoint.Application()
        oApp.Visible = True
        oApp.WindowState = PowerPoint.PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized

        oPres = oApp.Presentations.Open(alReportName)
        oPres.Slides.Range(2).Delete()
        oPres.Slides.Range(2).Delete()
        oPres.Slides.Range(2).ApplyTemplate(sTemplate)

      For Each slideImage In imageArr

  'this next line is the one that's not doing what I want
            oSlide = oPres.Slides.Add(3, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly)

           'code to add the image to the slide here - this part works

            oSlide = Nothing
      Next slideImage

end sub
```

Comment: I figured a Solution:
  
oPres.Slides.Range(2).Delete() 
oPres.Slides.Range(2).Delete()
oPres.Slides.Range.ApplyTemplate(sTemplate) 
oPres.Slides(2).CustomLayout() = oPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)

For Each slideImage In imageArr 
 oSlide=oPres.Slides.Add(3,PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly)
 oPres.Slides(3).CustomLayout() = oPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2) 
 oSlide = Nothing 
Next slideImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a Solution:

```
oPres.Slides.Range(2).Delete() 
oPres.Slides.Range(2).Delete() 
oPres.Slides.Range.ApplyTemplate(sTemplate) 
oPres.Slides(2).CustomLayout() = oPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2) 
For Each slideImage In imageArr 
    oSlide=oPres.Slides.Add(3,PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly) 
    oPres.Slides(3).CustomLayout() = oPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2) 
    oSlide = Nothing 
Next slideImage
```